# How to change SoapUI testRequest method to get instead of Post

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client, webservice-client

I need to change the request method to GET instead of the default one POST in  SoapUI 5.3.0.

ٍSteps

1. Open SoapUI.
2. Create new project.
3. Add WSDL.
4. Add New Test suite.
5. Add New Test case.
6. Add new Soap Request step.

When I run the test step and check the HTTP log I find that the default method is POST.

How I can change the method to GET.

Comment: I do not think you that you can change. It comes as part of wsdl, I guess.

Comment: With SOAP, you send a xml body to the server, so it will always send a POST request. Why do you want a GET request ?

Comment: Other part is requesting me to send it as GET